# java fork join framework: why the threads are not stealing job from each other?

Tags: java, multithreading, forkjoinpool

Below is my Fork-join Sample Code.It is supposed to compute max number in an array which it is doing correctly.But In Code I am not able to see threads stealing job from each other.steal count is 0 most of the times. What is going wrong?

```
package MultiThreading;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class MaxValueUsingForkJoin {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Random random = new Random();
        int arraysize = 500;

        int[] arr = new int[arraysize];
        System.out.println("arraysize : " + arraysize);

        for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
            arr[i] = random.nextInt(50000);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        Task_MaxValueF task = new Task_MaxValueF(arr);
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();

        forkJoinPool.execute(task);

        do {
            System.out.printf("******************************************\n");
            System.out.printf("Main: Parallelism: %d\n", forkJoinPool.getParallelism());
            System.out.printf("Main: Active Threads: %d\n", forkJoinPool.getActiveThreadCount());
            System.out.printf("Main: Task Count: %d\n", forkJoinPool.getQueuedTaskCount());
            System.out.printf("Main: Steal Count: %d\n", forkJoinPool.getStealCount());
            System.out.printf("******************************************\n");


            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (!task.isDone());
        forkJoinPool.shutdown();
        int result = task.join();
        System.out.println("Highest Number :" + result);


    }


}
```

Below is the implementation for recursive task

```
class Task_MaxValueF extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {

    int[] array;
    final int THRESHOLD = 10;


    Task_MaxValueF(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer compute() {

        if (array.length > THRESHOLD) {

            return ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(CreateSubTasks()).
                    stream().
                    mapToInt(completedTask -> completedTask.join()
                    ).max().getAsInt();

        } else {
            if (array.length > 0)
                return processing(array);
            else
                return -1;
        }

    }

    List<Task_MaxValueF> CreateSubTasks() {
        Task_MaxValueF task1 = new Task_MaxValueF(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, THRESHOLD));
        Task_MaxValueF task2 = new Task_MaxValueF(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, THRESHOLD, array.length));
        List<Task_MaxValueF> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(task1);
        list.add(task2);
        return list;
    }

    private Integer processing(int[] arr) {
        //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is Processing " + Arrays.toString(arr));
        // OptionalInt optionalInt = Arrays.stream(arr).max();
        int max = 0;
        for (int i : arr) {
            if (i > max)
                max = i;
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

Output :

```
arraysize : 500
[11079, 44714, 48871, 31643, 18782, 43247, 27394, 18218, 10496, 16913, 21932, 12119, 39829, 49303, 3584, 38235, 27041, 16614, 39585, 34167, 48994, 15103, 19147, 1632, 6229, 47797, 28629, 1911, 30696, 32825, 13986, 6212, 9290, 7092, 11926, 41903, 20527, 4384, 43814, 22090, 37184, 47395, 45544, 12478, 25359, 36682, 39290, 10865, 10423, 15070, 29118, 22049, 26834, 9141, 29155, 31248, 39237, 8519, 27519, 16555, 36198, 45867, 47928, 2088, 15726, 16126, 27954, 7052, 43609, 46032, 26594, 48775, 11449, 13659, 12001, 4781, 30123, 5824, 31629, 13233, 40369, 48208, 15177, 10944, 28270, 67, 46949, 22199, 13425, 49305, 25688, 12305, 3337, 37019, 4761, 13265, 28838, 44413, 43358, 22681, 45296, 10690, 15723, 31365, 11217, 17004, 30012, 24615, 20621, 23551, 48702, 40800, 46818, 31008, 4263, 29303, 2714, 33695, 8438, 49417, 43693, 4830, 9765, 35741, 10036, 6093, 12555, 24274, 43048, 25028, 40814, 36328, 15753, 47260, 29125, 43080, 24219, 45370, 9628, 22113, 10714, 12153, 37057, 37968, 11326, 18483, 21915, 14619, 6553, 21787, 18874, 17866, 25037, 10058, 13769, 834, 5532, 49541, 3872, 10383, 35495, 14663, 39414, 6238, 32343, 30000, 27364, 32805, 15498, 32634, 31461, 25567, 12741, 1379, 35289, 26215, 27801, 47276, 16153, 38960, 10112, 36797, 28932, 10126, 12518, 47714, 26648, 47925, 42884, 8615, 21053, 2573, 15143, 30283, 4155, 49886, 20111, 24564, 29004, 29294, 4356, 8959, 26107, 6692, 2291, 34641, 23755, 38856, 40839, 320, 41173, 10601, 16290, 37159, 42106, 36138, 32522, 25018, 27159, 9850, 10513, 25366, 29462, 35726, 18508, 43267, 2816, 29774, 33221, 778, 2096, 30089, 47276, 11069, 2771, 39365, 35608, 34791, 36812, 3335, 38075, 22210, 24756, 33835, 6612, 48622, 23854, 24097, 2686, 35028, 10872, 7860, 39174, 31960, 28638, 28776, 37866, 35444, 6777, 11695, 29996, 38727, 21733, 23560, 28406, 4649, 7280, 45542, 30647, 26009, 41981, 33928, 8507, 23990, 1465, 45818, 13417, 39654, 11253, 49991, 407, 43478, 30065, 21992, 41608, 27695, 5066, 31710, 43253, 24241, 5579, 42040, 32441, 5487, 38319, 14849, 25205, 14775, 30246, 33706, 18069, 28779, 33541, 6559, 23066, 9729, 46856, 25113, 19462, 38419, 7107, 5456, 20823, 12100, 21958, 10410, 11274, 6640, 30958, 3588, 3297, 34319, 30824, 14859, 31247, 35846, 43665, 343, 29759, 2121, 24490, 40854, 40469, 29217, 41143, 22017, 24556, 2246, 41941, 13757, 2847, 10185, 22667, 19680, 3523, 49329, 2666, 365, 4705, 43104, 39246, 8366, 20914, 41153, 45719, 41613, 41635, 19216, 16049, 30639, 44311, 30853, 43678, 17949, 36012, 24319, 36502, 38705, 29157, 12649, 23253, 42777, 39223, 9004, 6706, 41643, 28592, 28321, 15856, 28134, 32001, 22993, 27294, 9024, 44876, 24619, 9353, 27041, 2792, 41473, 13089, 1915, 20833, 47695, 21048, 34325, 3005, 1304, 24311, 27442, 19049, 8079, 13163, 38531, 34866, 39824, 41437, 38038, 16912, 15049, 46175, 19752, 12701, 35848, 5057, 43022, 963, 11826, 41220, 15004, 30978, 45564, 8054, 41457, 17265, 37274, 1100, 27439, 36301, 33138, 10142, 8378, 28365, 37724, 36747, 48845, 17973, 12168, 19117, 18819, 34409, 33836, 21016, 17896, 9929, 46409, 36428, 34429, 14395, 29945, 7642, 24098, 31639, 20951, 26820, 16867, 4395, 22298, 47852, 18754, 6271, 38959, 7294, 48317, 38499, 26227, 16074, 16331, 40692, 37898, 42121, 48568, 12173, 40143, 43425, 16858, 10730, 6728, 9619, 33600, 16312, 16532, 28562, 34054, 30585, 21556, 10958, 23079, 36579, 22708, 38782, 28736, 47032, 42453, 34157, 38269, 32160, 39832, 4811, 4210]
******************************************
Main: Parallelism: 1
Main: Active Threads: 1
Main: Task Count: 0
Main: Steal Count: 0
******************************************
******************************************
Main: Parallelism: 1
Main: Active Threads: 1
Main: Task Count: 0
Main: Steal Count: 0
******************************************
******************************************
Main: Parallelism: 1
Main: Active Threads: 1
Main: Task Count: 0
Main: Steal Count: 0
******************************************
******************************************
Main: Parallelism: 1
Main: Active Threads: 1
Main: Task Count: 0
Main: Steal Count: 0
******************************************
******************************************
Main: Parallelism: 1
Main: Active Threads: 1
Main: Task Count: 0
Main: Steal Count: 0
******************************************
******************************************
Main: Parallelism: 1
Main: Active Threads: 1
Main: Task Count: 0
Main: Steal Count: 0
******************************************
******************************************
Main: Parallelism: 1
Main: Active Threads: 1
Main: Task Count: 0
Main: Steal Count: 0
******************************************
******************************************
Main: Parallelism: 1
Main: Active Threads: 1
Main: Task Count: 0
Main: Steal Count: 0
******************************************
******************************************
Main: Parallelism: 1
Main: Active Threads: 1
Main: Task Count: 0
Main: Steal Count: 0
******************************************
******************************************
Main: Parallelism: 1
Main: Active Threads: 1
Main: Task Count: 0
Main: Steal Count: 0
******************************************
******************************************
Main: Parallelism: 1
Main: Active Threads: 1
Main: Task Count: 0
Main: Steal Count: 0
******************************************
Highest Number :49991

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your array size is far too small. The fork/join pool is running everything in a single thread, so there is nothing to steal.

Comment: Need bigger array. Maybe a few hundred million.

Comment: I would also say your logic is rather suboptimal - ideally you want to fork one task, then execute the other in the current task. That way you don't end up with lots of waiting threads. Also, creating lots of lists isn't ideal from a performance standpoint. Tasks should take tens to hundreds of milliseconds each.

Comment: Is there anyway to force stealing on threads?
I want to see it working.